# Sticky footer: why could overflow:auto; and position:relative; be needed?

Tags: html, css, position, overflow, sticky-footer

I'm using css sticky footer from [http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/style.css)

Why do we need: `#main{overflow:auto;}` and `#footer{position: relative;}`?

Seems like it works without it (I'm not talking about Opera and IE fixes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`overflow:auto;` will simply add the scroll bar if the page is longer than what can be displayed based on your screen height. I've used it before and believe it ensures your footer stays visible at the bottom of the page when you scroll.

Have you tried it on a page that is longer than the screen can display to see how it behaves?

Quote from [cssstickyfooter.com](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/using-sticky-footer-code.html):

> **No Need for Clearfix Hack!**
>
> Many CSS designers will be familiar with the Clearfix Hack. It solved
>   a lot of problems with floating elements. A previous version of this
>   Sticky Footer solution used it. Instead, a more modern and easier to
>   code solution is the overflow statement. We apply it to the main 
>   to help get the footer to stick in Chrome. It also solves issues that
>   come up when using a 2-column layout where you float your content to
>   one side and your sidebar to the other. The floating content elements
>   inside the main  can cause the footer to become un-stuck in some
>   browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You might not need it but if needed `overflow:auto` makes an element act as a container that expands itself to contain it's floating elements (if any exists).

If you use firebug you can see what I mean by using it with overflow and click on the container `element#main`. It will stretch over the containing elements.

Without it the container element stays as small as possible and doesn't "contain" the other elements.

Read more here:

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html